# Callback function seems to be never called

Tags: laser, callback, roscpp, node, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

This question follows [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/36200/subscribing-to-topic-throw-compilation-error/).

Now my node is compiling and executing, but it seems that the callback function is never called on the subscription to lasers. */scan* is remapped to */base_scan* (that send data, according to rostopic echo /base_scan ).
As far as I understand, every time the node gets a message, it should trigger the callback and I should get a console output, a rxconsole output and the robot should move a little. I don't get what can fail in this case.

What's wrong with the code or what should be done to be sure that the node really gets the data ?

Sources :

```
  BrController::BrController(ros::NodeHandle &nh) : target_frame_("/base_controller/command")
 {
/* Node handle that manage the node and provide publishing and subscribing function */
nh_ = nh;

/* Set up the publisher for the cmd_vel topic : we'll publish on this topic to drive the robot */
 cmd_vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/base_controller/command", 1);

scan_filter_sub_ = nh_.subscribe("scan", 50, &BrController::msgCallback, this);
 }

void BrController::msgCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan & msg)
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist base_cmd;

    std::cout << "Callback" << std::endl;
    ROS_INFO("Callback");

   base_cmd.angular.z = 50;
   cmd_vel_pub_.publish(base_cmd);

   std::cout << "published command : [" << base_cmd.linear.x << " " << base_cmd.linear.y << " " <<  base_cmd.linear.z << "][" << base_cmd.angular.x << " " << base_cmd.angular.y << " " << base_cmd.angular.z << "]"<< std::endl; 
}


bool BrController::driveBraitenberg()
{
  //we are sending commands of type "twist" to drive the robot
  geometry_msgs::Twist base_cmd;

  while(nh_.ok())
  {
     // Nothing is done as we want the robot to be driven from the laser input  
   }

  return true;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36223/callback-function-seems-to-be-never-called/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-11**:
derekjchow is right... ros::spinOnce() is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you need to call ros::spinOnce() in the while loop in driveBraitenberg

See [this article](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-06-11**:
Okey, problem solved, I was thinking I did that in the main, but seems that not.